# Updating multiple records massing assignment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a shows when a store was last visited. I want to be able to update multiple stores at once if they were all visited on the same day.

I think I have most of the code but I can't figure out how to get rid of the mass assignment error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: date_visited(1i), date_visited(2i), date_visited(3i)

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"put",
"authenticity_token"=>"/yr8kLOyrTRGPfG1f/I5ilY/QB6GUx9IhQj6WiBaibM=",
"store_ids"=>["4",
"5"],
"visit"=>{"date_visited(1i)"=>"2012",
"date_visited(2i)"=>"11",
"date_visited(3i)"=>"14"},
"commit"=>"Save Visit"}
```

Model

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :date_visited, :spent, :store_id
    belongs_to :
end
```

Controller

```
def update_multiple
  @visits = Store.find(params[:store_ids])
  @visits.each do |visit|
    visit.update_attributes(params[:visit])
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Updated products!"
  redirect_to stores_path
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for :visit, :url => update_multiple_visits_path, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
<ul>
  <% @visits.each do |visit| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "store_ids[]", visit.id %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date_visited %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :date_visited %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>

<ol id="route">
  <% @visits.each do |store| %> 
    <%= content_tag_for :li, store do %>
      <%= "#{store.store} - #{store.address}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Comment: Visit belongs to store. Each store can have many visits. I'm just trying to track when the last time someone went to each store

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are missing the `attr_accessible :your_model_attributes` is this case, `:visits_attributes` on your activerecord model definition.

Also, your params should look like

```
{ visits => 
  { id_1 => 
    { :store_id
      :attributes_for_visit_1 }
  }
  { id_2 =>
    { :store_id
      :attributes_for_visit_2 }
  }
} # and so on....

# visits_controller.rb
  def update_nultiple_visits
    @visits = Visits.find(params[:visits].keys).each{|visit|visit.update_attributes!}
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `Store` model

```
attr_accessible :visits_attributes

accepts_nested_attributes_for :visits
```

And I'd suggest changing your controller to this:

```
def update_multiple
  @stores = Store.find(params[:store_ids])
  @stores.each do |store|
    store.update_attributes(params[:visit])
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Updated products!"
  redirect_to stores_path
end
```

Comment: I'm still getting the mass assignment error, even if I try to only update one record

Comment: Explain what you are doing here in your form: `<%= hidden_field_tag "store_ids[]", visit.id %>`. Why are you putting the `id` of each visit inside an array named store_ids?

Answer (score -1):

Helper date_select generate three a select tags (for year, month and day).
You can concatenate its before updating attributes.
For example:

```
Date.civil(params[:visit][:date_visited(1i)].to_i, params[:visit][:date_visited(2i)].to_i, params[:visit][:date_visited(3i)].to_i)
```

Comment: No, you don't need to concatenate those params, Rails should be doing that automatically. That's not the problem.